# Large (in meters) landscape mesh has artifacts on peaks only at certain scale

Tags: blender, aframe

I made a mesh from a Digital Elevation Map that spanned 1x1 degree box of geography, but when I scale the mesh up to 11139m in blender I get these visible jagged shadows on the peaks of the mesh. I'd prefer to not scale everything down but I suppose I can, it just seems like a strange issue I want to better understand.

My goal is to use the landscape in a WebVR application, but when I put this mesh into an Aframe scene it also has this issue. Thanks for any tips!

[image: jagged shadows blender]

[image: jagged shadows aframe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Quick answer:

I think this may be caused by the **clipping start/end** values. Also called **near/far clipping planes**. Adjusting them may fix the issue but also limit the rendering distance.

#### Longer explanation:

Take a look at this:
[image]

It's a simple grayscale, but imagine it is scaled across your entire scene depth (Z depth buffer). The range of this buffer is set by the start/stop clipping (near/far) camera setting.

By default Blender has its start/stop (near/far) clipping set to 0.01 - 1000.
While A-Frame has it like 0.005 - 10000. You may find more information here: [A-Frame camera #properties](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/camera.html#properties)

That means the renderer has to somehow fit every single point in that range somewhere on the grayscale. That may cause overlapping or Z-fighting because it is simply lacking precision to distinguish the details. And that is mainly visible at edges/peaks because the polygons are connected there at acute angles and the program has to round up the Z-values. That causes overlapping visible as darker shadows (most likely the backside of the polygon behind).

You may also want to read more about Z-fighting because it is somewhat related.

#### Example

[image]

[image]